# пагинация спарсеного контента через ajax

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос с пагинацией, вопрос заключается в следующем, я подгружаю через ajax контент, контент в виде:

```
<div class='card'>card description</div>
```

Таких дивов может быть и 10 штук а может быть 1000, то есть я не могу контролировать лимит данных как если бы я брал их из БД. Может направит кто на правильный путь какой выбрать подход для данной ситуации?

Comment: Так вам нужно ограничить количество выводимого контента, или реализовать пагинацию?

Comment: реализовать пагинацию, ограничение контента не рассматривается по специфическим причинам

Comment: Я написал рабочее решение, но оно совсем макаронный паттерн. Не хотел бы сюда выкладывать. Давайте я или скину вам в лс куда-нить, чтобы вы разобрались и сделали хорошо, или отрефакторю, как будет свободное время и пришлю в ответ